# javascript: what is the 'console' context in the example below?

Tags: javascript

Reading through [this article](http://blog.sourcing.io/interview-questions) about good interview questions for a JS coder linked off of HN today and got to the following part:

> Next I'd ask a few simple questions designed to show me how well
>   candidates understood the arguments object. I'd start off by calling
>   the as-yet undefined `log` function.
>
> `log('hello world')`
>
> Then I'd ask the candidates to define `log` so that
>   it proxies its string argument to `console.log()`. The correct answer is
>   something along these lines, but better candidates will often skip
>   directly to using `apply`.

```
function log(msg){   
    console.log(msg); 
}
```

> Once that's defined I change the way I call `log`, passing in multiple
>   arguments. I make clear that I expect `log` to take an arbitrary number
>   of arguments, not just two. I also hint to the fact that `console.log`
>   also takes multiple arguments.
>
> `log('hello', 'world');`

The way that the writer explains his solution is via `apply`:

> Hopefully your candidate will jump straight to using apply. Sometimes
>   they'll get tripped up on the difference between apply and call, and
>   you can nudge them to the correct direction. Passing the `console`
>   context is also important.

```
function log(){
  console.log.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

I get here that the `log` function is leveraging `apply` and implicitly passing `arguments` in, so that a call like

```
log('hello', 'world');
```

will pass along `console.log.apply(console, ['hello', 'world'])`, though my question is: what is the `console` context in this example, i.e. the first argument in the `apply` call above, and where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console` is just the object that has the `log` function defined on, and is, essentially, `this` in the `log` function, which is why it is being passed as the context. `console` is not some special word in the browser, it's just an object that was saved under `window.console`.

Comment: ah, that seems obvious now. so if you call `console.log` using `apply` like this, it's also important to pass along the `console` context.